# How to define TypeScript type for object wrapper that has string as a key & React SFC as a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, object-literal

Following is the Form component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@helpers/ImportProxy';
import { mockApi } from '@constants/api';

type Props = {
  // formValues: any
};

type MapKindToComponentT = {
  [key: string]: React.SFC
}

/** @component */
export const Form: React.SFC<Props> = __props => {
  const renderQuestions = () =>
    mockApi.map(
      (question, index): React.ReactElement | undefined => {
        const mapKindToComponent: MapKindToComponentT = {
            radio:        Elements.RadioElement,
            text:         Elements.InputElement,
            email:        Elements.InputElement,
            url:          Elements.InputElement,
            checkbox:     Elements.CheckBoxElement,
            dropdown:     Elements.SelectElement,
            textarea:     Elements.TextareaElement,
        };
        if(mapKindToComponent[question.kind]) {
          const Element = mapKindToComponent[question.kind];
          return <Element key={index} question={question} />;
        }
      }
    );

  return (
    <form>
      {renderQuestions()}
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Value of each key of `mapKindToComponent` is React functional component.

Following is the error I get for it's currently defined type. Works fine with `any`.

> Type error: Type 'FunctionComponent' is not assignable to type
>   'FunctionComponent<{}>'.   Types of property 'propTypes' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type 'WeakValidationMap | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<{}> | undefined'.
>         Type 'WeakValidationMap' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<{}>'.
>           Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Props'.  TS2322

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

Make it explicit that `MapKindToComponentT` accepts function components of any kind.

```
type MapKindToComponentT = {
  [key: string]: React.SFC<any>
}
```

**Explanation**

The default type parameter (the one that describes `Props`) for `React.SFC` defined in `@types/react` is `{}`.

```
type SFC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

If a component expects some more precise type as its props, for example `{ foo: string }`:

```
declare const SomeComponent: React.SFC<{ foo: string }>;
```

such a component will not be assignable to `React.SFC`.

```
const MyComponent: React.SFC = SomeComponent;      // ⛔️ Compile-time error
const MyComponent: React.SFC<any> = SomeComponent; // ✅ OK
```

Comment: Ah it was only missing last bit! Thank you @Karol